# Cache API responses to MySQL - is that good practice?

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I am using an API which has a limit on requests. The API response is in XML and typically it is around 8 kB big.To say short: I want to eliminate to exactly send the same requests twice to the API.

There can be over 2 million requests with their appropriate answers. So when I get that amount of XML responses copied to records in MySQL, **will it respond fast enough if I query it?**

Table structure:

- id int PK Auto Increment
- request_parameters TEXT UNIQUE
- response TEXT

I found MySQL Query Cache, but I think its only handy for much requested requests. The other will  maybe slow down?
I also found Varnish, but it seems to me more a HTML/code cache.

Comment: _"will it respond fast enough if I query it"_ Will it break if I look at it? Populating a database with some random 8 KB text and a few parameters can easily be realized, and the answer will be more accurate than any of us can guess.

Comment: Why won't you simply get array from xml (I think you already to that), serialize that array and save in files on server's filesystem. This is dirty way but very fast. You can also use third-party caching.

Comment: @CodeCaster You are right, I am setting up a test now on my laptop. The results will be shown within a hour. Question left: is it good practise to cache it this way. Thanks

Comment: use memcached or if MySQL is used - a MEMORY table

Comment: @PLB save all XML files in a directory will be faster as MySQL query?

Comment: @DelphiLynx I don't see any problems, apart from invalidating the cached data: remember to implement a method to remove records, since the cached API response might become outdated.

Comment: @DelphiLynx No, you understood wrongly. I don't know what happens to your xml in your script. If you use one to use its content in your script, you must be converting one to array. So if you serialize this array and save it as `.txt` file and read one back instead of trying to get xml again will be faster.

Comment: For 8KB XML, consider hashing the XML and indexing on the hash.

Comment: Oke, half a million of records are already a problem for MySQL with the above setup. Maybe the MEMORY table will do the trick. Any other suggestions for BEST practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume:

- you only need to fetch a `response` from a given `request_parameters` (`...WHERE request_parameters = 'some string'`)
- `request_parameters` are not too long (under 1000 characters)

I advise:

1. Drop your ID column. Although some people recommend always using an integer as a primary key, I understand you are not trying to build a relational database. You just need one table for storage.
2. Change your `request_parameters` column types to `VARCHAR(x)`, "x" being the largest expected size of a parameter string.
3. Make `request_parameters` the primary key.
4. As advised by PLB, store the serialized version of your XML responses.

2 millions rows of such data will require several Gb, plus some space for the index. If you have a hell lot of available memory on your system, and if you can afford loosing all your data when you restart MySQL, then you might want to go for a try with MEMORY table.

Comment: Thanks, thats a complete answer to my question!